# how can read more than one value in variable with shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Read more than one value in variable space seprated

I have a variable that stores output of command. Sometimes output of command is single word and sometimes output command is having multiple words with space separated

Example

```
MAC=  00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe
echo $MAC
```

I want to use if statement like below

if $mac has more than one word then echo not ok else echo ok

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting value from below
MAC2=`grep -w "$MAC" juniper.conf | awk '{sub (/;/,"");print}'| awk '{print $4;}'`
it generally grep match entry from file

Comment: @l0b0 `MAC= ...` *is* valid shell code; it's just interpreted in a completely different fashion. It adds `MAC` (with a null value) to the environment of the following command.

Comment: @chepner You're right, I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

you should not have the space after the `MAC=`.

try

```
awk '{print (NF>1?"not ":"")"ok"}'  <<<$MAC
```

e.g.

```
kent$  MAC="00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe 00:1c:c4:5b:6e:fe"

kent$  awk '{print (NF>1?"not ":"")"ok"}' <<<$MAC                                   
not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply determine if there are spaces in $MAC, you can do:

```
case $MAC in  
     *\ * )
           echo "not ok"
          ;;
       *)
           echo "ok"
           ;;
esac
```

Comment: this works but if i put this before my if else conditions script stop working if matched with any of above rule.

I want if-else statement so my further code should also run.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if [[ "$MAC" =~ "\s" ]]; then echo not ok; else echo ok; fi
```

The following would yield the string before the first occurrence of  (whitespace):

```
address=${MAC%% *}
```

Comment: can i read word instead of space 
first 6 words i want read is this possible as your script is running fine.

Comment: i have finished it up with word count thanks for kind reply and support
warm regards,